# How does Mathematica estimate error on fit parameters?

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, implementation-details

When performing a fit using `NonlinearModelFit` (or any of *Mathematica* fitting functions, but I am particularly interested in nonlinear models), *Mathematica* makes a covariance matrix available for all the fit parameters.

I was wondering if anyone has an idea of how *Mathematica* does this error estimation on parameters?

Comment: Similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/how-does-mma-compute-confidence-intervals/37901#37901)?

Comment: And this:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149841/how-does-mathematica-calculate-the-standard-error-during-a-non-linear-fit/149884?noredirect=1#comment401840_149884.

Answer (score 4):

According to Mathematica documentation and my own calculations direct answer is:

```
errorList = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
```

where `cov` is covariance matrix, and errorList list of parameter uncertainties in given order. Next, `cov` in Mathematica is accessible as:

```
cov=nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]
```

or it can be estimated from [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)

$H_{i,j}=\frac{\partial^2 RSS}{\partial x_i\partial x_j},$

where $RSS$ is [residual sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) at best fit point and $x_i$ are fit parameters. Finally,

$\mathrm{cov}=\frac{2 RSS }{n-k}H^{-1},$

where $n$ is number of points and $k$ number of fit parameters. Full expression:

$\mathrm{errorList}=\sqrt{\frac{2 RSS}{(n-k)}\mathrm{Diagonal[}H^{-1}\mathrm{]}}.$

Answer (score 3):

The statistics are computed from a linear approximation around the best fit. It is described in the Documentation Center -> Virtual Book under "Statistical Model Analysis" in [the subsection on "Nonlinear Models"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html#144989606).