# How does Mma compute Confidence Intervals?

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics, implementation-details, modeling

I am trying to understand how Mma computes the Confidence Intervals after a `NonlinearModelFit`. Consider the following example:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data, Joined -> False], Plot[Normal@nlm, {x, 0, 8}],ImageSize -> 200]
(*out*)
```

[image: Fitting results]

Which comes with the following R squared and confidence intervals:

```
nlm["RSquared"]
nlm["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]

(*Out*)0.957573
(*Out*)
```

[image]

The table above assumes the default 95% Confidence Interval and, I am assuming, normal distribution around `a=1.50632` and `b=1.42633`.

Questions:

1. How does Mma estimate the Standard Error of `a` and `b`?
2. The mean used to estimate such confidence intervals is the sample mean, i.e. ~2.6667?

I could not find in the documentation how this was done from a fitting. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Standard errors and confidence intervals from linear and nonlinear regressions are obtained from the covariance matrix.  Details about the covariance matrix can be obtained [here](http://www.unc.edu/~jjharden/methods/vcv_week3.pdf).

Briefly, the square root of the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix gives us the standard errors:

```
se = Sqrt[nlm["CovarianceMatrix"]] // Diagonal
(* {1.10159, 0.600123} *)
```

The confidence interval is obtained by multiplying the standard error by the value of Student's t for the given confidence level and degrees of freedom.  For this set of data, the degrees of freedom is 4 and for a confidence level of 95%

```
ci = InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[4], 1 - 0.05/2]
(* 2.77645 *)
```

Thus, we obtain the last column of the `ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable`:

```
Transpose[{{a, b} - se ci /. nlm["BestFitParameters"], 
   {a, b} + se ci /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]}]
(* {{-1.55217, 4.56481}, {-0.239879, 3.09254}} *)
```

Note that this method assumes that the error in the parameters is normally distributed, which is probably not the case for a nonlinear model.  I would be hesitant to rely heavily on the confidence intervals reported by Mathematica in light of this issue.  If you have access to the following journals, [this article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100374a068) presents a monte carlo method for deriving confidence intervals that doesn't require the assumption of normality and the jacknife method (I can't put my finger on the reference I use, but several options show up with a google search) is fairly straightforward to implement.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I was afraid that the Standard errors would be, in some way, associated to the initial search values that I attributed to the free variables, but I see this isn't the case. Thank you for your input!

Comment: The standard errors can be easier calculated using `nlm["ParameterErrors"]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries True - I was focusing on the how part.