# How to compute "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable"-Values on validation data with NonlinearModeFit?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, nonlinear, modeling

When I perform a NonlinearModelfit I get a FittedModel object and I can see the values of the property "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable".
Now I apply the FittedModel object on a new data case (a validation data case) and get the estimated model value for this case.
But I need additionally the confidence interval for this single predicted response for the validation case like I can see it for each data case in the training data. Is it possible to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval)

> prediction intervals predict the distribution of individual future
>   points, whereas confidence intervals and credible intervals of
>   parameters predict the distribution of estimates of the true
>   population mean or other quantity of interest that cannot be observed.

You can obtain the single prediction intervals for a new data point as shown below.  `sp` contains the 1, 2 & 3 standard deviation single prediction intervals based on the sample data.

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x];

{sd1, sd2, sd3} =
  2 (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #] - 0.5) & /@ {1, 2, 3};

{bands68[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} = Table[
   nlm["SinglePredictionBands",
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {sd1, sd2, sd3}}];

(* new data *)
x0 = 4;

sp = Flatten[{nlm[#], bands68[#], bands95[#], bands99[#]} &@x0];
sp2 = {x0, #} & /@ sp;

Show[
 Plot[{nlm[x], bands68[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]}, {x, -1, 8},
  Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}],
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]],
 ListPlot[sp2, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]],
 AxesOrigin -> {-1, -9}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, {-9, 13}},
 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[Partition[Rest[sp], 2],
 TableHeadings -> {{"σ=1", "σ=2", "σ=3"}, None}]
```

> ```
> σ=1  |  2.16509      4.21813
> σ=2  |  0.611601     5.77162
> σ=3  |  -2.76111     9.14433
> ```

Comment: The factor 2 is the rule of thumb for 1.96, correct? Should one use the Student rather than the Normal distribution, because the number of data points is known even though small?

Comment: @Volker The `SinglePredictionBands` function uses Student's t-distribution under the hood.  You can see the calculation for a linear case demonstrated here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69819/363

Comment: @Volker The factor 2 is two standard deviations, for which the confidence level is [0.9545](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). I.e. `sd = 2; cl = 2 (CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], sd] - 0.5)` and in reverse: `sd = Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - (0.5 - cl/2)]`.  1.96 is the number of standard deviations representing the [95% confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96), i.e. `sd = Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - (0.5 - 0.95/2)]`.  They are used interchangeably, but it's more precise to state which is being used: std dev or confidence level.