# How to Work Student t-Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm working with the sampling distribution of the sample mean and sample variance. For my data, I have the following sample mean = 0.418, standard deviation = 0.306, and degrees of freedom = 44. I've determined the 95% confidence interval (CI) is [0.3266,0.5099]

Below is the plot the Student t-distribution for these parameters. My questions are as follows:

1. How can I color the area under this distribution to show the 95% CI?
2. How can I use NIntegrate to verify the area between the 95% CI is 0.95?

> ```
> Plot[PDF[StudentTDistribution[0.418, 0.306, 44], x], {x, -1, 2}, 
>  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
> ```

Comment: To find confidence intevals, look at [36827](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36827/how-does-mma-compute-confidence-intervals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
pl1 = Plot[
   PDF[StudentTDistribution[mean = 0.418, stDev = 0.306, degFr = 44], 
    x], {x, -1, 2}, PlotRange -> All];
pl2 = Plot[
   PDF[StudentTDistribution[mean, stDev, degFr], x], {x, 0.3266, 
    0.5099}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
Show[{pl1, pl2}]
```

But your confidence interval does not seem right, because the above gives:
[image]

Comment: ya; I will have to look into that ... thank u Nicholas!

Comment: @PRG And the corresponding `NIntegrate` is `NIntegrate[
 PDF[StudentTDistribution[mean, stDev, degFr], x], {x, 0.3266, 
  0.5099}]`. It is considered good form to accept and like answers.

Comment: yes, Nicholas ... I hadn't finished the correspondence.